# How to hide port 80 on Azure WebApp

Tags: azure, security, azure-web-app-service, port

Currently we have HTTPS only setting enabled for our web app. But for security reasons we want to completely hide port 80. How is it possible?

So the online port scanners would return only 443 as available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this directly from the WebApp. Azure WebApp is a PAAS service not IAAS. You don't have to worry about this infrastructure security issue; Azure takes care of it.

A **real** security enhancement will be to place your WebApp behind a network service - such as App Gateway or Front Door - which will hide port 80 on the WebApp but more importantly add a network security layer to your infrastructure.

Comment: FrontDoor does not allow hiding of ports too (same as WebApp)

Comment: Indeed @JoeBloggs. Technically, whatever the port of the WebApp, it will still be available. I said "hide" because the WebApp will no longer be the endpoint, and the WebApp can block all Internet input. So from the Internet point of view, the WebApp is hidden and so is its port.

Comment: Gotcha. To clarify my original question - the purpose of hiding is security audit. To not show port 80 as opened on our public url

Comment: It all depends on your security team. If you want to remove the public endpoint completely - and so the port -, and not just block with the WebApp firewall, you can use an App Service Environment and deploy your webapp in a VNET. But this is more expensive.